# How to get an offline Haskell debug trace?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

In the Haskell docs here http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Debugging  it mentions Hat to do offline debug traces, but that page is online. I found it via Google but it seems outdated; what is the best way to do offline Haskell traces?

Comment: Are you talking about stack traces? You might want to check out http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ExplicitCallStack

Comment: I need something which allows me to start a program which generates an offline trace; http://www.cs.york.ac.uk/fp/ART/ does that, but is outdated. I was wondering (but guess not) if there is a new alternative for it.

Comment: It would help to know what you're trying to accomplish. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 2):

Hat isn't outdated -- olaf chitil revived it and is actively maintaining it: http://olafchitil.github.com/hat/

The latest version on hackage is tested to build with ghc 7.6.

It does, however, still only work on Haskell 98, with a few extensions. So programs that use more advanced GHC extensions (particularly regarding fancy type tricks) won't work with it. To my knowledge, there's nothing similar to `hat` that's been extended to handle a wider range of extensions to Haskell.